# Azure keyvault 'sign' API - questions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

1. Referring to the Azure keyvault Sign API at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/sign/sign. Its not clear if the "value" which is string (in request and response both), how the API expects the encoding for binary strings like digest and how the response has this 'value' encoded? Is this in base64? If so, Azure has any difference in base64? Any sample code showing this REST API request/response processing?
2. Looking for help in understanding how (and if) we can use the ‘Sign’ API to sign the X509 digital certificate.If we generate or upload the Keys (private key – corresponding to the root CA cert), can that key be used to sign a digital certificates issued by this CA. If so, what would be the right steps to do this. In my understanding, take the digest of the x509->cert_info, encode this digest in base64 and call Azure 'sign' API. Once we have the response, append the signature to X509 certificate (that was being signed i.e. x509->signature with this signature). Would be great if you could share code example.

Comment: Question 1 is duplicated and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526851/414058

Comment: For question 2, of course you can use Key Vault to sign a certificate, but before you can even think on calling the Sign API, you must reach a point where you know the signature algorithm (`sha1WithRSAEncryption`, `sha256WithRSAEncryption`, etc) and you have the digest in binary format. Also, your question doesn't specify the language, which makes hard for anybody to provide sample code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Keyvault Sign API - Request body "value" encoding format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503318/azure-keyvault-sign-api-request-body-value-encoding-format)

Comment: @fernacolo Did you solve this? I'm still on a hunt for C# sample code. I can't seem to understand how to create a x.509 with the fetched signature I get back from the Sign() API. Also, what exactly do I digest? the CSR? thanks